# MATLAB sending matrix part as a whole matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a `3600*140*140` matrix the it be called `theMat`

And I have function that works on `N*N` matrix let it be called `Foo`

I try to send it, but i see that:

```
size(theMat(23,:,:))
```

Is

```
[1,140,140]
```

And I wanted it to be

```
[140,140]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `squeeze()` for that:

```
size(squeeze(theMat(23,:,:)))
[140 140]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
test(:,:)=theMat(23,:,:);
```

Comment: Sorry, you're right, this actually works. I was thinking of first setting test as a 2D matrix, then doing test=theMat(23,:,:), so without indices on test. That will get you the error. Apologies.

Comment: Actually, what I suggested is faster than using squeeze.  Elapsed time is 0.000053 seconds, for running `temp=ones(30,30,30);  test(:,:)=temp(28,:,:);` versus
Elapsed time is 0.000144 seconds, for running `test=squeeze(temp(28,:,:));`